# backward-kill-word in vim?

Tags: vim

is the quickest way to go back and kill a word `Esc` or `Ctrl-[` and `db`? I guess I mess up a lot :P and am used to using `M-<backspace` or `Ctrl-<backspace>` in other editors (or word processors). Still getting the hang of this (vim), but switching to normal-mode for short tasks like this one seems an odd way to go about it. Just wanted to inquire if there was anything better than what I was doing... Thanks much ~

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In insert mode you can use <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> to undo the most recently typed word.

Comment: Just a note, it doesn't *undo* in relation to vim's undo/redo stack.  It just deletes to the previous word-divide character.  Typing it again will continue the deletion.

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for `<c-w>` in insert and command modes ? (like in unix shell command line) Or `db` in normal mode?

Answer (score 4):

Try <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where is your cursor positionned, `<c-w>` or db won't delete all of the word.
try dib / dab to select the all word (with or without space) regarless of where you are in the word.